# How can I access a google sheet shared with my client_email from the service account created on the cloud console

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

### Context

A google sheet, sheetX was created and is updated manually by an external group of people. I would like my application's server to periodically extract certain information (e.g. every morning using a cronjob).

### Issue

Access occurs without user interaction so the Oauth2 flow seems a bit out of reach.

**Possible Solutions?**

- Should I have them share the sheet with my personal account, have
  myself perform the oauth flow once on the server and keep the token
  forever? => This method doesn't feel right as I feel there are
  several issues such as the token expiring leaving no one able to
  access the data...
- Use an API key somehow? After sharing the doc with the email for my **service account** for my project, I created an APIkey. I've tried using calling the `googleapiclient.discovery.build` with an `developerKey=myAPIkey` but ended up with a 403, "The caller does not have permission"

**additional**

I was trying to use another method [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html) but no such luck for me.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2 Tried this?

Comment: thank you, it worked, the link I used neglected to enable the google drive APIs in favor of the Sheets API alone. Quick question, I'm sorry if i'm being a bit pushy, is there any way to achieve this using v4 Sheets API ?
Edit: nvm I just used the creds from the serveAccountCredentials.from_json_file with the googleapiclient.discovery.build and it worked well, ty again !

Comment: Good to hear that, I have added it as the answer for others to find it easily. Please select it as the correct answer if it solved the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here!](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2)
This should work as given in this comments.

For Sheet v4 API, [read this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).